# how to set the tab order for the UI controls in win 32?

Tags: c, winapi, dialog

hello all I have a small dialog which I created dynamically, which has a textbox and a button..if the user presses the TAB key it has to switch between the two control(textbox and button)...I tried using SetwindowPos...but it doesnt seem to solve my problem...please give me a solution for this..in the below code..I also tried to include the mainwindow in the taborder..still it doesnt work

//dialog creation

```
HWND dialogHandle = CreateWindowEx(0,WC_DIALOG,L"Security Alert",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,600,300,280,160,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

//create textboxcontrol within the dialog
    HWND textBoxHandle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,L"EDIT",L"",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE |ES_PASSWORD | WS_TABSTOP,123,48,110,25,dialogHandle,(HMENU)IDD_TEXTBOX,NULL,NULL);

    //create button
    HWND buttonHandle  = CreateWindowEx(NULL,L"Button",L"OK",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE| WS_TABSTOP,151,85,85,25,dialogHandle,(HMENU)ID_PASSWORD_OK,NULL,NULL);
```

//setwindowpos

```
SetWindowPos(NULL,textBoxHandle,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
SetWindowPos(textBoxHandle,buttonHandle,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your message loop, you need to call [`IsDialogMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645498%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for keyboard events (such as the tab key) to be processed by the dialog box. This is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644995%28VS.85%29.aspx#keyboard_iface).

Here is an example:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    if (!IsDialogMessage(dialogHandle, &msg)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried the below..it dont seem to work

while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
 {
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
  IsDialogMessage(textBoxHandle,&msg);
  IsDialogMessage(buttonHandle,&msg);
 }

Comment: @Rakesh: You need to pass the dialog handle, not the control handles. I've added an example.